# How to get data from response body

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

Im working right now with Youtube API in Java, and managed to get some data stored as `CommentThreadListResponse`

Here is an example of its node, but list contains about 100 of them.

```
{
   "snippet" : {
     "topLevelComment" : {
       "snippet" : {
         "textDisplay" : "SOME COMMENT"
       }
     }
   }
 },
```

So there is just `textDisplay` that remains, as something I'd like to extract into String. So my question goes "How can I do it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let take your response and analyse it, for make it more understandable I will place some index values, and consider response **comment**

```
//index0    {
        "id": "11",
        "snippet": {
            "topLevelComment": {
                "snippet": {
                    "textDisplay": "SOME COMMENT 2 "
                }
            }
        }
    },

 //index0   {
        "id": "22",
        "snippet": {
            "topLevelComment": {
                "snippet": {
                    "textDisplay": "SOME COMMENT 2"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

You will get your response in above format, so to get details of each snippet navigate through indexes

`comment[0]` will extract the first element of the response.

`comment[0].id` will extract the first element id of the response.

`comment[0].snippet` will extract the first snippet of the response.

`comment[0].snippet.topLevelComment` will extract the first snippet's topLevelComment of the response.

So on like this we can read response and get the data we need in your case you need to get textDisplay so you can use following code,

```
comments[0].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay
```

To go through all indexes you can use for-each as following

```
for (x in comments) {

  comments[x].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear the structure of data y r getting completely from yr question but:

```
var comments = [
{
  "id": "1111",
   "snippet" : {
     "topLevelComment" : {
       "snippet" : {
         "textDisplay" : "SOME COMMENT 2 "
       }
     }
   }
 },
{
  "id": "222",
 "snippet" : {
     "topLevelComment" : {
       "snippet" : {
         "textDisplay" : "SOME COMMENT 2"
       }
     }
   }
 },
]'
```

you need a serilization lib, checkout [How to deserialize json string into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860614/how-to-deserialize-json-string-into-object)
then

```
for(var i = 0; i < comments.length; ++i)
  comments[i].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay
```